# In how many ways 8 people can be arranged in exactly 2 out of 6 hotels?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Would love some help with my probability homework…thanks in advance! :)
“ In how many ways 8 people can be arranged in exactly 2 out of 6 hotels? ”

Thanks for the comments, message received:)

This is what I’ve tried:
-First person have 6 options to choose from.
-2nd person can either choose like the first - 6 options, or chose different. If 2nd decide to chose different it’s 6*5=30 options because 1st person can be in 6 different places and each time 2nd person have 5 options to chose from. So 2nd person sum is 36 options.
-3rd person and on, have 3 scenarios: everyone before him choose the same and he want to join - 6 options, or everyone before him choose the same and one would want to choose differently- 6x5=30, or the 2 hotels are set and one can go to each of them - 6+30+nCr(6,2)x2=66. Because there are 5 people with the same case it’s 5x66=330.
-last person faces these options: either there is a split and they choose - 2xnCr(6,2)=30. Or everyone are in the same hotel and they need to choose differently- 5x6=30. So last person total is 60 options.
The sum is 6+36+330+60=432 options which sounds like a small number:/ I also tried to drew the problem that how I came up with these calculations.

Thanks for the comments again, I hope my English is fine and understoodable;)

Comment: What have you tried? How do you personally think about this problem?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Would love to help if you could show what you have tried, and where you are stuck

Comment: I would actually love to know the answer to this. I'm a bit rusty on my combinatorics.

Comment: First choose the two hotels that are used. Then count the ways how you can arrange 6 people in two hotels (excluding the cases that all are in only one of the two hotels.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that by "arrange" people in hotels, you mean *assign* hotels to people

This is a case of putting **distinct objects into distinct boxes**, see [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/distinct-objects-into-distinct-bins/)

Now suppose there were only two hotels $A$ and $B$, then each person would have two choices, so the $8$ people would have $2^8$ choices except that one choice each would leave one of the hotels empty, so acceptable assignments would be $2^8-2$

But there are $6$ hotels, and any two could be chosen for assigning, so we need to multiply by $^6C_2$ to account for this, giving a final answer of $^6C_2\times(2^8-2)$

Comment: You can also search the topic on this site, you will find lots of answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand now :)

Comment: Glad to be of help  :-)